# Can I prevent a StreamReader from locking a text file whilst it is in use?

Tags: c#, .net, logging, concurrency, filelock

The StreamReader locks a text file whilst it is reading it.
Can I force the StreamReader to work in a "read-only" or "non locking" mode?

My workaround would be to copy the file to a temp location and read it from there but I would prefer to use the StreamReader directly if possible.
Any alternative suggetions?

Background:
I've written a small app to get some stats out of a log file. This file is constantly being updating (several times a second) by an outside program lets call AAXXYY.

Reviewing the output suggests that my app may be locking the file and preventing AAXXYY from writing.

This is what I'm doing

```
    private void btnGetStats_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int countStarts = 0;
        int countEnds = 0;

        IList<string> sessions = new List<string>();

        using(StreamReader stRead = new StreamReader(openFileDialog1.FileName,Encoding.Unicode))
        {
            while(!stRead.EndOfStream)
            {
                string line = stRead.ReadLine();
                if(line.Contains("Session start"))
                {
                    countStarts++;
                    sessions.Add(line.Substring(line.IndexOf("["), line.LastIndexOf("]") - line.IndexOf("[")));
                }
                if (line.Contains("Session end"))
                {
                    countEnds++;
                    sessions.Remove(line.Substring(line.IndexOf("["), line.LastIndexOf("]") - line.IndexOf("[")));
                }
            }
        }

        txtStarts.Text = countStarts.ToString();
        txtEnds.Text = countEnds.ToString();
        txtDifference.Text = (countStarts - countEnds).ToString();

        listBox1.DataSource = sessions;
    }
```

Answer (score 53, accepted):

You can pass a FileStream to the StreamReader, and create the FileStream with the proper FileShare value. For instance:

```
using (var file = new FileStream (openFileDialog1.FileName, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.ReadWrite))
using (var reader = new StreamReader (file, Encoding.Unicode)) {
}
```

Comment: +1 this works nicely. Thank you. Although I had to replace "var" with FileStream & StreamReader. What was var suppossed to do? Is that VB?
I think this answer should be edited to change those but I dont have the rep to do it myself

Comment: About the 'var' keyword, see this link: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383973.aspx. That keyword is new in C# 3.0+.

Comment: Aha. Thanks cloud. Serves me right for working in the dark ages. Shame I can't +1 a comment :-)

Comment: Oh, I can +1 a comment. There we go

Comment: You can also call the dispose method - reader.dispose() in this instance.

Comment: @Brian the [`using` statements](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/using-statement) call dispose automatically when they complete

Answer (score 6):

Thought I'd add some context, StreamReader **does not** lock a file for reading **only for writing** whist it is being read. Take a look at the code below from the StreamReader class.

```
 new FileStream(path, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read, FileOptions.SequentialScan);
```

Notice the default FileAccess.Read parameter taken for MSDN http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.fileshare.aspx

> Allows subsequent opening of the file for reading. If this flag is not specified, any request to open the file for reading (by this process or another process) will fail until the file is closed. However, even if this flag is specified, additional permissions might still be needed to access the file.

Again taken from MSDN to allow reading and writing use FileAccess.ReadWrite instead (as suggested by Jb Evain).

> Allows subsequent opening of the file for reading or writing. If this
>   flag is not specified, any request to open the file for reading or
>   writing (by this process or another process) will fail until the file
>   is closed. However, even if this flag is specified, additional
>   permissions might still be needed to access the file.