# File.ReadLines without locking it?

Tags: c#, file, stream, io, filestream

I can open a FileStream with

```
new FileStream(logfileName, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.ReadWrite);
```

Without locking the file.

I can do the same with `File.ReadLines(string path)`?

Comment: [The documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd383503.aspx) does not say anything about the locking behavior of ReadLines. Thus, even if it should turn out that the implementation of the .net Framework you use does not lock the file, it's not something that you can rely on when developing your application.

Answer (score 51, accepted):

No... If you look with Reflector you'll see that in the end `File.ReadLines` opens a `FileStream(path, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read, 0x1000, FileOptions.SequentialScan);`

So Read-only share.

(it technically opens a `StreamReader` with the `FileStream` as described above)

I'll add that it seems to be child's play to make a static method to do it:

```
public static IEnumerable<string> ReadLines(string path)
{
    using (var fs = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.ReadWrite, 0x1000, FileOptions.SequentialScan))
    using (var sr = new StreamReader(fs, Encoding.UTF8))
    {
        string line;
        while ((line = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
        {
            yield return line;
        }
    }
}
```

This returns an `IEnumerable<string>` (something better if the file has many thousand of lines and you only need to parse them one at a time). If you need an array, call it as `ReadLines("myfile").ToArray()` using LINQ.

Please be aware that, logically, if the file changes "behind its back (of the method)", how will everything work is quite undefined (it IS probably technically defined, but the definition is probably quite long and complex)

Comment: as far as ReSharper is a profiling tool, Reflector should be used in such case

Comment: @abatishchev: I wouldn't describe ReSharper as a profiling tool. I believe it can do decompilation now, too (possibly only in a beta release).

Comment: Why do you call your method `ReadAllLines` if it's behavior corresponds to `ReadLines` and not `ReadAllLines`?

Comment: @abatishchev I meant Reflector... My error... (I use both, but for different purposes). But from the next version (or so), Resharper will contain a "Reflector-like" module (this is because Reflector should have become pay-only from March). You can even use ILSpy or other programs.

Comment: @CodeInChaos because the Visual Studio didn't tag it as an error or as a warning (clearly it can't divine stupidity)... Is it enough? :-) I made the correction.

Comment: @ms007 The [`ReadLines`](https://github.com/dotnet/coreclr/blob/master/src/mscorlib/src/System/IO/File.cs#L507) uses a [`ReadLinesIterator.CreateIterator(path, Encoding.UTF8)`](https://github.com/dotnet/coreclr/blob/master/src/mscorlib/src/System/IO/ReadLinesIterator.cs#L99) that creates a [`new StreamReader(path, encoding)`](https://github.com/dotnet/coreclr/blob/master/src/mscorlib/src/System/IO/StreamReader.cs#L191) that in turn creates an internal `FileStream`. So no big difference.

Answer (score 2):

`File.ReadLines()` will lock the file until it finishes.

Comment: Answer should represent solution or at least should seem to be pointing toward that direction. Answer seeker already knows the fact you asserted so it does not do anything helpful.