# How to update a text file which always contains a single line?

Tags: c#-3.0

I have the following code to read a line from a text file.
In the UpdateFile() method I need to delete the existing one line and update it with a new line.
Can anybody please provide any ideas?
Thank you.

```
FileInfo JFile = new FileInfo(@"C:\test.txt");
            using (FileStream JStream = JFile.Open(FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.ReadWrite, FileShare.None))
            {
                int n = GetNUmber(JStream);
                n = n + 1;
        UpdateFile(JStream);

            }

private int GetNUmber(FileStream jstream)
        {
            StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(jstream);
            string line = sr.ReadToEnd().Trim();
            int result;
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(line))
            {
                return 0;
            }
            else
            {
                int.TryParse(line, out result);
                return result;
            }
        }

private int UpdateFile(FileStream jstream)
{
    jstream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
    StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(jstream);
    writer.WriteLine(n);
}
```

Comment: what is wrong with what you have?

Comment: The GetNumber() function works fine and it reads the line. But the UpdateFile() function is not working.

Answer (score 3):

I think the below code can do your job

```
StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter("file path", false); //false means do not append
writer.Write("your new line");
writer.Close();
```

Comment: In my case, I am not able to use the file path as I have the file opened using a stream within "using" block. I got an error message "The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process". Thanks.

Comment: pass the stream in the constructor of the StreamWriter

StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(youstream);

Answer (score 2):

If you're just writing a single line, there's no need for streams or buffers or any of that.  Just write it directly.

```
using System.IO;

File.WriteAllText(@"C:\test.txt", "hello world");
```

Answer (score 2):

```
var line = File.ReadLines(@"c:\temp\hello.txt").ToList()[0];
var number = Convert.ToInt32(line);
number++;
File.WriteAllText(@"c:\temp\hello.txt", number.ToString());
```

Manage the possible exceptions, file exists, file has lines, the cast......

Comment: Is there any way we can manage using streams. In my case I need to lock the file so that the file can be accessed by only one user at a time. So I tried to create a stream with FileShare.None option and "using" block.

Comment: Interesting I didn't know this http://www.dotnetperls.com/file-readlines the difference between File.ReadLines and File.ReadAllLines and this seems like the question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5338450/file-readlines-without-locking-it

Comment: Thanks for sharing the information. In my case, I need to lock the file in read and write modes so I think FileShare.None best suits my requirement.