# Readline Error While Reading From .txt file in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, error-handling

I have a Streamreader which is trowing an error after checking every line in Daycounts.txt. It is not a stable txt file. String lines in it are not stable. Count of lines increasing or decresing constantly. Thats why I am using a range 0 to 167. But

Here is the content of Daycounts.txt:  [Daycounts](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1U9HX.jpg)

```
Dim HourSum as integer
    Private Sub Change()
        Dim R As IO.StreamReader
        R = New IO.StreamReader("Daycounts.txt")
        Dim sum As Integer = 0
        For p = 0 To 167
            Dim a As String = R.ReadLine
            If a.Substring(0, 2) <> "G." Then
                sum += a.Substring(a.Length - 2, 2)
            Else

            End If
        Next
        HourSum = sum
        R.Close()
    End Sub
```

Comment: Use File.ReadAllLines instead

Comment: How can I do that? I have used this also: Dim a As String = R.ReadToEnd not working aswell

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't know how many lines are present in your text file then you could use the method [File.ReadAllLines](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s2tte0y1(v=vs.110).aspx) to load all lines in memory and then apply your logic

```
Dim HourSum As Integer
Private Sub Change()
    Dim lines = File.ReadAllLines("Daycounts.txt")
    Dim sum As Integer = 0
    For Each line In lines
        If line.Substring(0, 2) <> "G." Then
            sum += Convert.ToInt32(line.Substring(line.Length - 2, 2))
        Else
            ....    
        End If
    Next
    HourSum = sum
End Sub
```

This is somewhat inefficient because you loop over the lines two times (one to read them in, and one to apply your logic) but with a small set of lines this should be not a big problem

However, you could also use [File.ReadLines](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd383503(v=vs.110).aspx) that start the enumeration of your lines without loading them all in memory. [According to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5338450/file-readlines-without-locking-it), ReadLines locks writes your file until the end of your read loop, so, perhaps this could be a better option for you only if you don't have something external to your code writing concurrently to the file.

```
Dim HourSum As Integer
Private Sub Change()
    Dim sum As Integer = 0
    For Each line In File.ReadLines("Daycounts.txt")
        If line.Substring(0, 2) <> "G." Then
            sum += Convert.ToInt32(line.Substring(line.Length - 2, 2))
        Else
            ....    
        End If
    Next
    HourSum = sum
End Sub
```

By the way, notice that I have added a conversion to an integer against the loaded line. In your code, the sum operation is applied directly on the string. This could work only if you have [Option Strict](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zcd4xwzs.aspx) set to Off for your project. This setting is a very bad practice maintained for VB6 compatibility and should be changed to `Option Strict On` for new VB.NET projects

Comment: Thank you. That is what I was looking for!!