# Can two processes read from the same text file at the same time without error?

Tags: .net, file-io, concurrency, exacttarget

I'm having a weird issue with a proprietary software system.  Anyways, I think the only question I need answered is "can two processes in a .NET environment read from the same text file (file I/O) at the same time without error"?  The file in question is a 3gb CSV file.

Comment: Yes, absolutely, provided the file is opened with the correct sharing modes (otherwise you will get a sharing violation error when trying to open from the second app).

Comment: Thanks @500-InternalServerError, I forgot to mention though, The file in question is a 3gb CSV file.  Would this cause any issues?

Comment: No, the size of the file should not be a factor in this. What's the error you are getting?

Comment: "Cannot read from a closed TextReader" - I don't have access to the source code so I cannot get any more details than this.

Comment: @500-InternalServerError this error isn't consistent.  It's a weird one off error.  Most times I don't get any errors.

Comment: Sorry for being so vague, but my role isn't that of a developer anymore, so this is really all the information I have.  I understand that the answer I get will probably also be vague, and that's fine, just looking for a general direction.

Answer (score 0):

You can open the file with `FileAccess.Read` and `FileShare.ReadWrite` mode.

Check out this question:
[How can I read a text file without locking it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3448230/how-can-i-read-a-text-file-without-locking-it)

Comment: Right, I don't have access to modify or access the source code - my role isn't that of a developer anymore, so I guess I was asking more along the lines of generality.