# File.Create Async write keeps the file locked

Tags: c#, asynchronous, file-io

I need to write a file in a async way, every half a second. And I can only use **C#** on **.Net Framework 2.0** .

I tried using `File.Create` and `BeginWrite`. But it keeps the file locked, and I need to be able to access it (read). I tried fiddling with the security settings but I'm not really sure what I'm doing there.

Any help is appreciated!

Edit:

```
var bytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(stringBuilder.ToString());
var filePath = Path.Combine(OUTPUT_FOLDER, FILE_NAME);
var fileSteam = File.Create(filePath, bytes.Length, FileOptions.Asynchronous);
m_IAsyncResult = fileSteam.BeginWrite(bytes, 0, int.MaxValue, WriteCallback, new State(fileSteam));

private void WriteCallback(IAsyncResult ar) {
    var state = (State)ar.AsyncState;
    var stream = state.Stream;
    stream.EndWrite(ar);

    m_IAsyncResult = null;
}
```

Comment: We need to see your code, but that is generally indicative that you aren't closing a stream somewhere.

Comment: What code are you using to read it? I assume BeingRead? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.stream.beginread(v=vs.80).aspx

Comment: Hey, I've added my code in the original post, thanks!

Comment: @WilliamXifaras I'm reading it with windows open or copy, not with code (yet)

Comment: Did you try using a thread and synchronous IO? That is much easier on .NET 2.0.

Answer (score 2):

You need to make sure that the file is opened non-exclusively. Check this post [How can I read a text file without locking it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3448230/how-can-i-read-a-text-file-without-locking-it)

Comment: Hey, I was trying to open it or copy it with windows, not with code

Answer (score 0):

If you can use `File.WriteAllText` or `File.AppendAllText` both will handle the open and close for you allowing you to read again later without issue.