# How to access a text file in c# that is being used by another process

Tags: c#, system.io.file

I have text file which is being been used by modscan to write data into the file. At a particular time I have to read the data and save in database. In offline mode ie; without modscan using it I can read the data and very well save in database. however as it online with modscan it gives exception

> Cannot access file as it been used by other process.

**My code:**

```
using System.IO;
string path = dt.Rows[i][11].ToString();
string[] lines = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(@path);
```

path has `"E:\Metertxt\02.txt"`

So what changes I need to make in order to read it without interfering with modscan.
I googled and I found this which might work, however I am not sure how to use it

> FileShare.ReadWrite

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I read a text file without locking it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3448230/how-can-i-read-a-text-file-without-locking-it)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a `FileStream` to open a file that is already open in another application. Then you'll need a `StreamReader` if you want to read it line by line. This works, assuming a file encoding of UTF8:

```
using (var stream = new FileStream(@"c:\tmp\locked.txt", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.ReadWrite))
{
    using (var reader = new StreamReader(stream, Encoding.UTF8))
    {
        string line;

        while ((line = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
        {
            // Do something with line, e.g. add to a list or whatever.
            Console.WriteLine(line);
        }
    }
}
```

---

Alternative in case you *really* need a `string[]`:

```
var lines = new List<string>();

using (var stream = new FileStream(@"c:\tmp\locked.txt", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.ReadWrite))
{
    using (var reader = new StreamReader(stream, Encoding.UTF8))
    {
        string line;
        while ((line = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
        {
            lines.Add(line);
        }
    }
}

// Now you have a List<string>, which can be converted to a string[] if you really need one.
var stringArray = lines.ToArray();
```

Comment: can I do something like `using (var reader = new StreamReader(stream, Encoding.UTF8)) { string[] lines = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(@path);foreach (string line in lines){// Do something} }

Comment: The `while((line = ...` is very similar to a `foreach (string line in lines)`. It will iterate over all lines in the file, from beginning to end.

Comment: I've updated the answer, in case you really need a `string[]`.

Comment: I have tried your way ,its not giving error anymore however now its not reading. Any suggestions ?

Comment: Has `modscan` actually written anything to the file? What is its size on disk?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/88666/discussion-between-micke-and-mark).

Comment: I've updated the answer, adding `FileShare.ReadWrite` to enable access to a file in use by another process.

Answer (score 0):

```
FileStream fstream = new FileStream("@path", FileMode.Open,FileAccess.Read, FileShare.ReadWrite);
StreamReader sreader = new StreamReader(fstream);
List<string> lines = new List<string>();
string line;
while((line = sreader.ReadeLine()) != null)
    lines.Add(line);
//do something with the lines
//if you need all lines at once,
string allLines = sreader.ReadToEnd();
```