# Read file without locking

Tags: c#, file, locking

I want to read a file created by a VBA-script in Excel and continually edited by this tool with my C#-program (it opens the file every 5 seconds and reads the data). Unfortunately, as soon as I open my program to read from the file, Excel / my VBA-script is unable to write to the file anymore ("access denied").

This is my C#-Code:

```
    System.IO.FileStream fs = new System.IO.FileStream("file.txt", 
                                                        System.IO.FileMode.Open, 
                                                        System.IO.FileAccess.Read, 
                                                        System.IO.FileShare.ReadWrite);
    System.IO.StreamReader File = new System.IO.StreamReader(fs);
    // read lines from Stream
    File.Close();
```

Is there any possibility to continue writing to the file although it is opened in the C#-tool? I already tried copying the file before opening but I get the same error message.

Comment: You could try making a copy of the file for you to work with.

Comment: There's a similar question here with lots of good responses: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3448230/how-can-i-read-a-text-file-without-locking-it

Comment: "I already tried copying the file before opening but I get the same error message."
´System.IO.File.Copy("file.txt", "fileCOPY.txt", true);´
did not work either.

Comment: @NickT Unfortunately those answers only suggest him to use the `FileShare.ReadWrite` flag, which he is already using.

Comment: How are you reading the text from the stream?

Comment: @cubrr: I'm using the `StreamReader.ReadLine()` -method in a while-loop to read the text

Comment: how is your vba / excel writing ?

Comment: @Boo:
`Open "FilePath" For Output As #1`
and then
`Print #1, (Worksheets("Name").Range("A" & i).Value & "...")`
The `Print` statement is used inside a Loop to write several lines to the file.

The error occurs - according to the debugger - in the line with the `Open` statement

Comment: I've used `File.ReadAllText` for quick reads before, you can try catching the exception and waiting a short time for the other app to close, then trying again. It's a little wasteful.

Comment: After setting the file to "Shared" in the VB-Script and finding a bug in a different place in my script which caused the program to open the file twice, it works now. Thanks a lot for your help :)