# Reading a text file without locking it

Tags: c#

I have an app (not written by me, can't modify the code) which runs in two modes - GUI-based, or silent. It writes its progress to a log file. I've written a wrapper to turn it into a pseudo-command line app, using `System.Diagnostics.FileSystemWatcher` to monitor the log file, and any time it changes write the latest line to the console:

```
private static void OnChanged(object source, FileSystemEventArgs e)
{
    Console.WriteLine(File.ReadAllLines(e.FullPath).Last());
}
```

This was working perfectly, until there were two updates to the log file in quick succession, and suddenly the app spat out an error message: `System.IO.IOException: The process cannot access the file '<filepath>\Upgrader.log' because it is being used by another process.`

How can I redirect the log entries to the console, without locking the file? I've found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3448230/how-can-i-read-a-text-file-without-locking-it) answer, but I'm not sure how to use a FileStream to get the same effect.

EDIT:

So, if I have a dict to keep track of the log files:

```
Dictionary<string, FileStream> logDict = new Dictionary<string, FileStream>();
Dictionary<string, int> indexDict = new Dictionary<string, int>();
```

add an OnCreated event handler:

```
private static void OnCreated(object source, FileSystemEventArgs e)
{
    logDict[e.FullPath] = new FileStream(e.FullPath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.ReadWrite);
    indexDict[e.FullPath] = 0;
    OnChanged(source, e);
}
```

then change OnChanged to something like

```
private static void OnChanged(object source, FileSystemEventArgs e)
{
    using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(logDict[e.FullPath]))
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < indexDict[e.FullPath]; i++)
            sr.ReadLine();
        Console.WriteLine(sr.ReadLine());
        indexDict[FullPath]++;
        sr.Close();
    }
}
```

that should work?

EDIT AGAIN: I think I have a solution. Tried this and it seems to work:

```
Dictionary<string, int> indexDict = new Dictionary<string, int>();

private static void OnChanged(object source, FileSystemEventArgs e)
{
    if (!indexDict.Keys.Contains(e.FullPath))
        indexDict[e.FullPath] = 0;
    using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(e.Full Path,
                                          FileMode.Open,
                                          FileAccess.Read,
                                          FileShare.ReadWrite))
    {
        using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(fs))
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < indexDict[e.FullPath]; i++)
                sr.ReadLine();
            Console.WriteLine(sr.ReadLine());
            indexDict[e.FullPath]++;
            sr.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The duplicate exactly describes what you should do, with code and all. We can replicate the code, but there is no use in that. Explain what exactly you are having trouble with understanding.

Comment: Made edits for a proposed solution based on what I understand from the other answer. Am I on the right track?

Comment: I don't know. Why would you keep them in a dictionary. Just open and close them when you are done.

Comment: I also see no value in the dictionary.

Comment: So reopen the FileStream every time the event fires?