# Lock objects accessesd by threads using lock() in c#

Tags: c#, xml, locking

I am currently trying to read and write data to a xml file in c# using thread, I have a utilty class that has the function to read the XML file and then write the data into the xml. The way im doing it is as follows.

```
public class XMLUtil
{

 String lockingObject = "";

 public bool WriteToXml(Product product)
 {
   lock(lockingObject)
   {
       XDocument xDoc = XDocument.Load("file.xml")
   }

   //Code to add data to XElement

   xDoc.Add(xElement)
   lock(lockingObject)
   {
       XDocument xDoc = XDocument.Save("file.xml")
   }
 }

}


public class SomeOtherClass
{

   XMLUtil xmlUtil = new XMLUtil();

   private async void btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
     bool t = await Task.Run(() => xmlUtil.WriteToXml());
   }
}
```

```
static class Program
{

// default methods

while (true)
{
   t = await Task.Run(() => XMLUtil.CheckChanges());
   await Task.Delay(20000);
}


}
```

I also have a background thread that keeps checking for the changes in the XML file to reload the view to the user, because of that I still get the IO/Exception saying that the file is already been used so it cannot be open... How can I fix it?

Comment: How does `CheckChanges` work? If it is reading and comparing, it is opening the same file, then you need to use the same lock. However, you could use `FileSystemWatcher` and save some trouble.

Comment: You really need to address this either globally in your application (using a shared, static lock object), or by using the actual file locking and file sharing APIs provided in .NET (e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/a/3448307/224370).

Comment: CheckChanges() should lock on the same  lockingObject instance as WriteToXml() does. Also, Pavel's answer below makes a valid point. However, trying to get exclusive access to the file itself and use that as the main locking mechanism should be the thing to go for.

Comment: @Theraot The checkChanges method access the file and checks for the number of nodes every 20 seconds and then closes it

Comment: Why do this. Why not when you update the file, update view? You shouldn't have to sleep or poll to check this.

Comment: @CosminSontu would I be okay If I make both the methods static and use the locking object as Pavel mentioned below?

Comment: @Çöđěxěŕ This is for a cw and it mentions that the user can manually change the xml file and when it happens the ui should be updated....

Comment: @Rasheen Ruwisha, making methods static won't make a difference. What is more important is to handle the situations where file read / write attempts fail due to file already being locked by other threads.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Strings are interned in .NET ([MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.isinterned?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.8#System_String_IsInterned_System_String_) reference), you don't have to use them as a `lock` constructions. Try to define your `lockingObject` as

```cs
private static object lockingObject = new object();
```

And use it inside `lock`

Comment: im kind of lost.. even if I declare this static and call the function as XMLUtil.CheckChanges() will the locking object be initialized? Im new to programming so sorry for the noob questions.

Comment: oh okay thanks, then ill make both the methods static and then use this to lockingObject to lock()

Comment: @RasheenRuwisha You don't have to make both methods static, you can access the static `lockingObject` from instance method

Comment: Oh okay, Thanks for the help, appreciate it